# Origin and usage of "wild" in "my wildest dreams"?

Tags: etymology, american-english, british-english, phrase-usage

Collins Dictionary defines [wildest dreams](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/in-your-wildest-dreams) as:

> If you say that you could not imagine a particular thing in your wildest dreams, you are emphasizing that you think it is extremely strange or unlikely.

The idiomatic expression appears to be quite old as suggested by [Etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/word/wild)

> Wildest dreams attested from 1717.

and before that,  "wild" seemed to be used figuratively mainly about different forms of excitements:

> - Meaning "sexually dissolute, loose" is attested from mid-13c. Meaning "distracted with excitement or emotion, crazy" is from 1590s.

So, where does "wildest dreams" come from? What connotation of the term does the expression rely on to suggest something extremely unlikely? Was it originally an AmE idiomatic expression?

Comment: Your own source at Etymonline suggests that the “wildest dreams” interpretation immediately followed from the sense of “distracted with excitement or emotion, crazy”; my guess is that this “wildest” was originally used as a simple descriptive modifier of “dreams”, but later on, “wildest dreams” became a set phrase to refer to the “craziest” and most “uncultivated, untamed, undomesticated, uncontrolled” dreams.

Comment: The date 1717 suggests that it might be American? Not that there weren't any European settlers but it seems unlikely that they coined the expression.

Comment: Dreams are essentially "wild" in the sense you have no control over the proceedings. As dreams are wild, the wildest of them would be the extreme case.  It's rhetorical, with no more significance than as an intensifier.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - well the first pioneers certainly had their "wildest dreams".

Comment: For its meaning see: [Phrase Finder](https://www.phrases.org.uk/bulletin_board/48/messages/733.html), and [beyond one's wildest dream](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/beyond+one%27s+wildest+dreams) (or imagination) **1754**:  *In short, the notion of a proper sinless Perfection on earth, in natures so miserably disordered as ours, is [one of the wildest Dreams](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=3h4HAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA246&dq=%22Wildest+dreams%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiq4O6dw9DcAhVGhuAKHTX2BW0Q6AEIODAD#v=onepage&q=%22Wildest%20dreams%22&f=false), that ever abused the human Understanding*

Comment: [**The wildest Imagination**](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=-yVLpQ5NTSwC&pg=PA27&dq=%22wildest+imagination%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjh88GHxdDcAhVF2lMKHY6PCzUQ6AEINzAD#v=onepage&q=%22wildest%20imagination%22&f=false) *cannot form to it self on any occasion, higher Delight than I acknowledge my self to have been in all that Evening I chose.* (London, **1724**)